# Couldn't hover over a menu for it to collapse in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There is a menu button with the id "usermenucollapsed". I want to hover over it so that the menu will be appeared and give the logout option. I've identified the menu with its 'id' and have used moveToElement() on it to hover the menu for the menu to have appeared, but no luck. I've checked that the menu button is not in a frame ensuring switching to the frame is not required.

isDisplayed() is returning false while isEnabled is returning true.

```
<div class="mobile-bar">
        <ul id="toolbar" class="toolbar">
            <li id="quickcreatetop" class="create dropdown nav navbar-nav quickcreatetop">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    CREATE
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?module=Accounts&action=EditView&return_module=Accounts&return_action=DetailView">Create Account</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?module=Contacts&action=EditView&return_module=Contacts&return_action=DetailView">Create Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?module=Opportunities&action=EditView&return_module=Opportunities&return_action=DetailView">Create Opportunity</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?module=Leads&action=EditView&return_module=Leads&return_action=DetailView">Create Lead</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?module=Documents&action=EditView&return_module=Documents&return_action=DetailView">Create Document</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php?module=Calls&action=EditView&return_module=Calls&return_action=DetailView">Log Call</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="last">
                        <a href="index.php?module=Tasks&action=EditView&return_module=Tasks&return_action=DetailView">Create Task</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="" class="dropdown nav navbar-nav navbar-search">
                <button id="searchbutton" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default searchbutton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                    <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> </span>-->Search
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="searchbutton">
                    <form id="searchformdropdown" class="searchformdropdown" name='UnifiedSearch' action='index.php'
                          onsubmit='return SUGAR.unifiedSearchAdvanced.checkUsaAdvanced()'>
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="action" value="UnifiedSearch">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="module" value="Home">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="search_form" value="false">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="advanced" value="false">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control query_string" name="query_string" id="query_string"
                                   placeholder="Search..." value=""/>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"
                                                                                aria-hidden="true"></span>-->Search</button>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="desktop_notifications" class="dropdown nav navbar-nav desktop_notifications">
                <button class="alertsButton btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="alert_count hidden">0</span>
                </button>
                <div id="alerts" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">This information is not available</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <form id="searchform" class="navbar-form searchform" name='UnifiedSearch' action='index.php'
                      onsubmit='return SUGAR.unifiedSearchAdvanced.checkUsaAdvanced()'>
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="action" value="UnifiedSearch">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="module" value="Home">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="search_form" value="false">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="advanced" value="false">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control query_string" name="query_string" id="query_string"
                               placeholder="Search..." value=""/>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"
                                                                        aria-hidden="true"></span>-->Search</button>
                </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li id="globalLinks" class="dropdown nav navbar-nav globalLinks-mobile">
```

Required button is this.

```
<button id="usermenucollapsed" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default usermenucollapsed" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-expanded="true">
                </button>
```

```
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.id("usermenucollapsed"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that it's the only element with that ID on the page?

Comment: Yeah. There are more than one. Thanks.

Comment: So was that the issue?

Comment: I'm confused: title says "collapse", but from description seems you have trouble "expanding" it. So what are you trying to do - expand or collapse?

Comment: When you mouse hover the menu, a drop-down menu will be displayed that includes the 'Log Out' option. I was trying to click the 'Log Out'.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you asked, but in my experience, the easiest thing to do in these cases is to just use a javascript click on the logout button, and bypass having to hover over the menu in the first place. You can do something like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("logout button selector here"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```